# mPDF Blank pages or some sections missing

Tags: php, html, css, slim, mpdf

I'm tring to generate a pdf with mPDF and a slim framework application.

The code is the following:

```
<div class="pdf-header">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2" class="col-left">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="col-center">
                <p>CERTIFICADO ENERGÉTICO</p>
                <p><span class="pdf-text120">Nº ____________________</span></p>
            </td>
            <td class="col-right">
                <div class="pdf-header-info">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                V. marcda
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                V. realizada
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Docs. OK
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Processo adiantado
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="pdf-cell-border">
                                &nbsp;
                            </td>
                            <td class="pdf-cell-border">
                                &nbsp;
                            </td>
                            <td class="pdf-cell-border">
                                &nbsp;
                            </td>
                            <td class="pdf-cell-border">
                                &nbsp;
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="pdf-title">PEDIDO:</div>
```

the CSS is the following:

```
    body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11pt;
}

.pdf-header {
    width: 100%;
}

.pdf-header table{
    border-collapse:collapse;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
}

.pdf-header table tr td {
    width: 33%;
}
.pdf-header table tr td.col-left{
    /*background-color: #006699;*/
    text-align: left;
}

.pdf-header table tr td.col-center{
    /*background-color: #33cc99;*/
    text-align: center;
}

.pdf-header table tr td.col-right{
    /*background-color: #ffff99;*/
    text-align: right;
}

.pdf-header table tr td.col-cell{
    /*background-color: #ffff99;*/
    font-size: 50%;
    text-align: Left;
    width: 8%;
}

.pdf-text120 {
    font-size: 120%;
}

.pdf-cell-border {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.pdf-header-info {
    margin-left:50px;
    margin-right:50px;
    font-size: 60%;
}

.pdf-header-info table{
    font-size: 60%;
}

.pdf-title {
    background-color: #FABF8F;
}
```

the problem is that de pdf generated is a blank page.
But if i remove the ":" in last line of the html is generate a pdf but it is not well formatted according to the CSS.

If i generate html page, all appears right.

I also tried to make a new project without the slim framework and no twig, just PHP, mpdf and the above code. In this case the pdf is well generated.

Because of this i think de problem is some configuration in slim framework but what could it be?

Does someone have any clue about this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I discovered that if i remove the chars "º" and ":" de pdf is generated correctly.

Comment: update on this question: if i use "/" (html &#47;) it also breaks de pdf and only show a blank page.

Comment: Just for reference:
preg_replace maximum string limit: 1000000
String length: 1738
charset encoding: UTF-8